# vb.net reduce image file size with interpolationMode not working

Tags: .net, vb.net

after click button1, it give me test_reduce with 4.87 MB file size
original file size is 1.91 MB, InterpolationMode is not working at all...
i want to reduce file size from 1.91 MB to less than 1 MB with InterpolationMode

> original image: https://images.alphacoders.com/943/943148.jpg

this is my code

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jpg As Image = Image.FromFile("test.jpg")
        Dim tp As Bitmap = reduce(jpg, 1920, 1080)
        jpg.Dispose()
        jpg = tp
        jpg.Save("test_reduce.jpg")
    End Sub

    Private Function reduce(ByVal img As Image, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Image
        Dim imaf As New Bitmap(width, height)
        Dim pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imaf)
        pic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic
        pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
        Return imaf
    End Function
```

Comment: The Save() call actually creates a PNG file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jpg.Save("test_reduce.jpg")
```

change to

```
jpg.Save("test_reduce.jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```